# Basis, a beginner in the field needs some guidance

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $B = {p_1(t), p_2(t), p_3(t)}$, where$\\p_1(t)=t^2+t+1
\\p_2(t)=t^2+t+2 
\\ p_3(t)=t^2+2t+1$,

is a basis for $P_2$.

What is $(t^2)_B$ $∈ R^3$?

I dont really get the second question here? can someone explain it to me and guide me step by step towards the solution?

Comment: What don't you understand, exactly? Do you know what $P_2$ is? Do you know what a basis is? Do you now what the symbol $(t^2)_B$ is defined as? Being a beginner is perfectly fine; everybody starts there. Being helpless isn't.

Comment: $(t^2)_B$ means to write $t^2$ as linear combination of the given basis vectors.  That means you need to find numbers, A, B, and C, such that $t^2= Ap_1(t)+ Bp_2(t)+ Cp_3(t)= A(t^2+ t+ 1)+ B(t^2+ t+ 2)+ C(t^2+ 2t+ 1)= (A+ B+ C)t^2+ (A+ B+ 2C)t+ (A+ 2B+ C)$ for all t.  Since, in order that two polynomials be the same for all t, the coefficients must be the same so you need to solve the three equations A+ B+ C= 1, A+ B+ 2C= 0, and A+ 2B+ C= 0 for A, B, and C.

Comment: @user296602 ouch. Basically I am trying to understand the concept of basis and I dont have a teacher to explain things to me atm so things get a bit tricky. In this particular exercise, the only thing I dont get is what $(t^2)_b ∈R^3$ means; or in your words,what the symbol $(t^2)_B$ is defined as. Like, what am I asked to find in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show these polynomials are linearly independent.$$\\p_1(t)=t^2+t+1
\\p_2(t)=t^2+t+2 
\\ p_3(t)=t^2+2t+1$$

That is

$$ c_1(t^2+t+1) + c_2(t^2+t+2 )+c_3(t^2+2t+1)=0 \implies c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$

Then you have to find coefficients $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that $$ c_1(t^2+t+1) + c_2(t^2+t+2 )+c_3(t^2+2t+1)=t^2$$

These coefficients are coordinates of $t^2$ with respect to the basis $B =\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Write the matrix expressing the elements of $B$ with respect to the canonical basis $1,t,t^2$. Prove that the matrix is invertible by computing its determinant for instance.